# pandas merge dataframes generated inside a loop

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have dataframes like this (generated inside a loop and added to a list):

```
column  row data_503    plate
0   1   A   1   2
1   1   B   2   2
2   1   C   3   2
3   1   D   4   2

column  row data_280    plate
0   1   A   1   2
1   1   B   2   2
2   1   C   3   2
3   1   D   4   2

column  row data_503    plate
0   1   A   1   1
1   1   B   2   1
2   1   C   3   1
3   1   D   4   1

column  row data_280    plate
0   1   A   1   1
1   1   B   2   1
2   1   C   3   1
3   1   D   4   1
```

I do have a layout file which links maps the measurements to specific conditions:

```
column  row cond    plate
0   1   A   5   1
1   1   B   5   1
2   1   C   5   1
3   1   D   4   1
0   1   A   5   2
1   1   B   5   2
2   1   C   5   2
3   1   D   4   2
```

I can combine the dataframes like:

```
for df in df_list:
    layout= pd.merge(layout, df, on=['plate', 'row', 'column'], how = 'outer')
```

However, I always get `data_280_x` and `data_280_y` columns but I would like to obtain only `data_280` and `data_503` columns. Changing `outer` to `left` does not change anything.

Any ideas how I could obtain something like?:

```
column  row cond    plate    data_280    data_503
0   1   A   5   1    1    1
1   1   B   5   1    2    2
2   1   C   5   1    3    3
3   1   D   4   1    4    4
0   1   A   5   2    1    1
1   1   B   5   2    2    2
2   1   C   5   2    3    3
3   1   D   4   2    4    4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After merging strip down the suffixes and apply `ffill` to fill nan of previous columns over columns and drop the duplicate columns by keeping the last one so it will be completely filled i.e

```
layout.columns  = [i.strip('_x').strip('_y') for i in layout.columns]
layout.sort_index(1).ffill(1).loc[:,~layout.sort_index(1).columns.duplicated(keep='last')]
```

Output:

```
   column cond data_280 data_503 plate row
0      1    5        1        1     1   A
1      1    5        2        2     1   B
2      1    5        3        3     1   C
3      1    4        4        4     1   D
4      1    5        1        1     2   A
5      1    5        2        2     2   B
6      1    5        3        3     2   C
7      1    4        4        4     2   D
```

Comment: I do prefere this solution because it is the most versatile one

Comment: Glad to help @Moritz.

Comment: Problem is, this solution duplicates the data columns in my case but I might be able to tweak it.

Answer (score 3):

You can combine the `_x` and `_y` columns since they are not going to have any overlapping values (based on that layout df), something like this:

```
df['data_208'] = df['data_208_x'] + df['data_208_y']
```

Then you can just drop the `_x` and `_y` columns.

Update with example:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"column": [1, 1, 1, 1], "row": ["A", "B", "C", "D"], "plate": [1, 1, 1, 1], "data_503": [4, 5, 6, 7]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"column": [1, 1, 1, 1], "row": ["A", "B", "C", "D"], "plate": [1, 1, 1, 1], "data_280": [1, 2, 3, 4]})
df3 = pd.DataFrame({"column": [1, 1, 1, 1], "row": ["A", "B", "C", "D"], "plate": [2, 2, 2, 2], "data_503": [4, 5, 6, 7]})
df4 = pd.DataFrame({"column": [1, 1, 1, 1], "row": ["A", "B", "C", "D"], "plate": [2, 2, 2, 2], "data_280": [1, 2, 3, 4]})
layout = pd.DataFrame({"column": [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], "row": ["A", "B", "C", "D", "A", "B", "C", "D"], "cond": [5, 5, 5, 4, 5, 5, 5, 4], "plate": [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2]})

out = []
for df in [df1, df2, df3, df4]:
    _ = pd.merge(layout, df, on=['column', 'row', 'plate'], how='outer').dropna()
    out.append(_)

merged = out[0]
for df in out[1:]:
    merged = pd.merge(merged, df, on=['column', 'row', 'plate', 'cond'], how='outer')

merged = merged.fillna(0)

merged['data_280'] = merged['data_280_x'] + merged['data_280_y']
merged['data_503'] = merged['data_503_x'] + merged['data_503_y']

merged = merged.drop(['data_280_x','data_280_y','data_503_x','data_503_y'],1)
```

Gave me:

```
column  cond  plate row  data_280  data_503
0       1     5      1   A       1.0       4.0
1       1     5      1   B       2.0       5.0
2       1     5      1   C       3.0       6.0
3       1     4      1   D       4.0       7.0
4       1     5      2   A       1.0       4.0
5       1     5      2   B       2.0       5.0
6       1     5      2   C       3.0       6.0
7       1     4      2   D       4.0       7.0
```

Comment: What if you come across 50 columns with `_x` and `_y` suffix. ?

Comment: You can do a for loop for the last part as longs as you know the names of the 50 columns. Or you could get the column names from the `out` df above like `set(col for df in out for col in df.columns)`

Comment: I think you can improve the solution by adding string formatters with for loop  to access and add columns with suffixes and removing all the rows that contains `_x` and `_y`

Comment: interesting solution

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure this is the most sophisticated solution, but you could start by concatenating all data_503 and data_280 dataframes together, then merge them.

The code is not pretty, I have to run to work though :)

```
df_list = [df1, df2, df3, df4]

data_280_list=[]
for k in df_list:
    if 'data_280' in k.columns:
        data_280_list.append(k)

data_503_list=[]
for k in df_list:
    if 'data_503' in k.columns:
        data_503_list.append(k)


df_503= pd.concat(data_503_list)
df_280= pd.concat(data_280_list)

for df in [df_503, df_280]:
    layout= pd.merge(layout, df, on=['plate', 'row', 'column'], how = 'outer')
```

Comment: that was my first attempt. it will work but I hoped to find a more elgant one

Answer (score 0):

Use `pd.concat` to merge a list of DataFrame into a single big DataFrame.

Comment: Not as simple as a single concat. Observe the columns.